# Location Annotation Images

Tags: image, firebase, annotations, location, callout

I am currently working on a function where the user can tap on a maps annotation and be taken to another screen which will hold an image of that location. I am using Mapbox and the tapOnCallout function to segue to another view controller (imageLocationViewController) which will hold an image view.

The issue I am facing is letting this imageLocationViewController know which annotation has been clicked and therefore which image should be shown. I am using firebase to hold my data and within the annotation data I have a photoUrl which holds the relevant image.

I am currently able to print the relevant name of the annotation and photo Url when I am segueing. However, once I am within the imageLocation View Controller I believe I lose this data?

Does anybody know how I can pass this data into the new view controller so that I can pass the correct photoUrl into the image view.

This is my current code to segue to the imageLocationViewController.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) {



    if let annotation = annotation as? SkateAnnotation {



        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SkateImageSegue", sender: annotation.id)

        print("YourAnnotation: \(annotation.photoUrl)")

    }
}
```

Update ** Code for prepare for segue

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EditSaveSpotSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! EditSaveSpotViewController
        destination.parkId = sender as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: My issue is my code already contains  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

Comment: Could you show that code Cal?

Comment: Hey chris, I have updated the code. This segue takes me to a pop over where I edit the annotation information

Answer (score 0):

I would set a local variable whenever your mapView delegate function fires, just before you call `performSegue`, and then use that variable in `prepareForSegue`. See below

```
 var annotationId: String = ""

 func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) {



    if let annotation = annotation as? SkateAnnotation {


        annotationId = annotation.id
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SkateImageSegue", sender:self)

        print("YourAnnotation: \(annotation.photoUrl)")

    }
}


 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EditSaveSpotSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! EditSaveSpotViewController
        destination.parkId = annotationId
    }
}
```